# If I store a Refinery module with minerals in the bins, do they stay there?

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

Pretty much what the title says, really.

I have a Refinery module in my ship, with 4 bins containing between 20% and 85% of a mineral. If I swap the module out for something else and put it into storage, do the part-resources get stored along with it, or are they lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just going ahead and doing it which answered the question - yes, you lose the partial minerals (and you get a warning about it):

[image: Store dialog for a refinery, warning that the unprocessed minerals will be lost.]